# Not applying transformation to web.config in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, web.config-transform

I created a new configuration called "Staging", right-clicked on the main "web.config" and selected "Add Config Transform". Now there is a "Web.Staging.Config" file under the main "Web.config" file.

In Visual Studio Team Services, I have set the "Configuration" to "Staging".

[image]

The MSBuild arguments are...

> /p:Configuration=Staging /P:DeployOnBuild=True
>   /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /P:DeployIISAppPath=Path.Staging
>   /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
>   /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
>   /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://DOMAIN/MsDeploy.axd
>   /P:UserName=*** /P:Password=***

Upon deploy, the main Web.config has not been transformed.

What am I doing wrong? This works when I use the standard "Debug" configuration, which Visual Studio tells me is the 'active' configuration.

Comment: Did you check in the "Web.Staging.Config" file into source control?

Comment: Yes, its in the project.

Comment: Can you share the build logs?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT any resolutions? We have a similar issue but the warning appears in release logs as `Unable to apply transformation for the given package` and says verify the following: `Whether the Transformation is already applied for the MSBuild generated package during build. If yes, remove the <DependentUpon> tag for each config in the csproj file and rebuild`. Tried this but didn't work

Comment: @amythn04 We are experiencing the same issue. Did you find a resolution?